# Virtualbox not recognizing USB, drag 'n drop not working either

Tags: usb, virtualbox, drag-and-drop

I installed Virtualbox a few days ago and wanted to copy something from the host to the guest but realized it's not happening. I tried it with Windows and a couple of Linux distros but nothing works. Also I've installed the virtualbox extension pack that's supposed to support USB 1-3 and installed the guest-additions-iso. Drag 'n drop and shared clipboard also do not work.
The version I'm running is Version 6.1.34_Ubuntu r150636 and I also made sure that the extension pack is the same version. What am I missing?

Comment: did you install guest additions?

Comment: Forgot to mention that... I've installed the guest additions iso as well